# Switch the first and last letter of multiple words in a string

Tags: java, string, char

I am not sure how to approach this problem. I've seen people using arrays but after trying it, it only worked for the whole string and not each words individually.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to handle each word individually. Do you know how to get a list of words from a String?

Comment: I do not sadly:/ - I can search about it

Comment: First split the string into words then do the operation to make it simple

Comment: shows us here what you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the split method to split the string into multiple words, saved in a String array. Then, get the first and last letter using the charAt method, and then concatenate them in the correct order to get the modified word.

```
        String a = "This is a string with multiple words";
        String[] arr = a.split(" "); //splits string into an array of strings, by separating with spaces
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) //looping through each word 
        {
            if (arr[i].length() == 1) //don't change word if it only has 1 letter
            {
                System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
                continue;
            }
            //using charAt to obtain first and last letter of each word
            char firstLetter = arr[i].charAt(0);
            char lastLetter = arr[i].charAt(arr[i].length()-1);
            String middle = arr[i].substring(1, arr[i].length()-1); //all letters of word except first and last 
            arr[i] = lastLetter + middle + firstLetter; //concatenating together to create new word
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); //printing each word after switching letters 
        }
```

You seem like a beginner to Java, so I highly recommend you read the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) on the String class and its methods, as Java has some pretty thorough and relatively easy to understand documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! and I will check out the link for help in the future!

Comment: No problem, happy to help.